# MySQL_How to sum values in each two column that has the same value on another column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am very new to `MySQL` and only know about basic `CRUD` queries.

[image]

Values in host_team and guest_team represent the unique id of Team.

What I would like to do is summing up all the goals no matter which column that team belongs to.

So the result should be  `[10:0, 20:4, 30:3, 40:0, 50:4]`.

My approach is summing value in host_goals and guest_golas if value of host_team and guest_team are the same.

Since I am very unaware of `MySQL`, I have no idea where to start.

What would be the best approach in this case?

Comment: Can you post the table in a code block, and not an image?

Comment: Also, at no point do I see team 40, which is mentioned in your result.

Comment: Your expected output does not agree with the sample data.  Maybe the sample data got truncated or maybe you copied wrongly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this with a union:

```
SELECT team, SUM(goals) AS goals
FROM
(
    SELECT host_team AS team, host_goals AS goals FROM yourTable
    UNION ALL
    SELECT guest_team, guest_goals FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY team;
```

Comment: Am I doing it wrong by trying to work out a db-fiddle and trying to compare to his results, instead of just firing off a query as an answer ASAP?

Comment: @FrankerZ No, you're right.  For some reason, I thought I checked a couple of teams and convinced myself that the output makes sense.  It doesn't, but I think my answer is what the OP actually wants here.

Comment: Still, it's a shame